# How to select a drop down menu value using robot framework?

Tags: angularjs, python-2.7, selenium, robotframework, selenium2library

How to select a order number from the drop down list. 
Page has a similar 2 more drop down with same *ng-repeat*. when i try to select some text, it selects matching text from other drop down.
text equals also failed.

HTML:-

```
<select ng-repeat="select in controller.getSelects() track by select.key" ng-attr-name="select-{{select.key}}"  name="select-liftId">
<option value="ALL" ng-if="select.default" class="ng-scope">ORDER NUMBER</option>

<option ng-repeat="v in select.options" value="cdfd8775-1114-462b-8a47-bc7a93e0d6ab" ng-selected="v['_id'] === controller.values[select.key]" class="ng-binding ng-scope">   3</option>

<option ng-repeat="v in select.options" value="4f790134-31ab-4212-b152-c5c4101fbe5c" ng-selected="v['_id'] === controller.values[select.key]" class="ng-binding ng-scope">   2</option>

<option ng-repeat="v in select.options" value="8cfb28d3-955c-45b1-877f-56b67edad6ff" ng-selected="v['_id'] === controller.values[select.key]" class="ng-binding ng-scope">   1</option>
```

What i tried so far:

```
click element   repeater=v in select.options@row[2]


click element   xpath=//option[text() =${label})]

click element   xpath=//option[contains(text(),'${label}')]
```

I would greatly appreciate any help.. Thanks.

Updated:
This helped me for now...
click element //select[5]/options[3]

Answer (score 0):

click element   xpath=//select/option[@value="8cfb28d3-955c-45b1-877f-56b67edad6ff"]

Answer (score 0):

You need to list the option list first using get elements 
then click those list using index